# overflow button on jellybean

Tags: android

I am developing an application with target Sdk 17. My current device is Nexus 7.
My app should be without an action bar so I am using the theme *Theme.Holo.NoActionBar* on the activity.

I want to show the overflow button (3 dots) at the bottom right (next to the recent task). but I can't make it to be visible. If I return the action bar I see it at the top right, but that's not what I want.

Is there any idea for anyone?

Comment: Show code that dont work, and be brief in your explaination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `OptionsMenu` button you must use `ActionBar`, or you can set `android:targetSdkVersion="10"` for your project in manifest file. This will enable compatibility behaviour and you will see menu button near other navigation buttons .

Comment: Thanks, but my target SDK has to be 17

Comment: If it has to be 17, it is not possible to archive this. Options menu button at the bottom of the screen is used only for compatibility purpose, so in this situation only you can do is use action bar or move you menu actions to main interface of your app as a custom buttons or bar. EDIT:Are you sure you definitely need target 17?

Comment: Yes, it must be. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! P.S. You can upvote or check my answer as a correct one if my answer is correct or if it helps you.